# Matplotlib dates x axis wrong distance

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, intervals

I'm having trouble in arranging correctly the dates labels on my X axis in my plot. I put the graph image so you can better understand my problem.

[image: plot of wrong dates]

And here there is the code that creates the graph:

```
plt.figure()
x_axis = []    # contains the date value
y_axis = []    # an integer value
x_values_str = []    # contains the date representation

for data in json.loads(trend.trend_values):
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data[3]), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')

    x_axis.append(dates.date2num(date_obj))
    y_axis.append(str(data[2]))
    x_values_str.append(str(data[3]))

    plt.xticks(x_axis, x_values_str, rotation=45)
    plt.plot_date(x_axis, y_axis, tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, linestyle='-', marker='D',color='g')

    plt.title("Vowel: " + trend.vowel)
    plt.margins(0.1)
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
```

So, the problem here is that the X values are not equally-distanced among each other. How can I adjust the interval ?
Thanks

Comment: Is your problem that the labels overlap, or that the midpoint of the labels  are aligned with the tick marks? The overlap is caused by the data points are from the same date, and the alignment  is the default. Do you want the datapoints to have the same distance, but labelled with the dates?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I want the datapoint have the same distance but labelled with the dates. I mean, I want the datapoint to be equally distribute out along the x axis. I hope you understood my goal :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `x_axis` should be a integer range, instead of a list of dates, then you will get all data points with a distance of `1`, but labelled with your dates from `x_values_str`.

`x_axis.append(range(1,len(data[3])+1))`